# updating a tuple not giving error while tuples are immutable

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

I know that tuples are immutable but the following code is not giving
me any error:

```
tup=(1,2,3,4)
tup=()
print(tup)
```

Please can anyone help me understand why the statement 2 is not giving me any error?

Comment: By using the second line tup=() it essentially reallocates memory for the variable. Any logical control on a tuple is not going to work when it is being reinitialized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why it's not giving you an error is because the variable `tup` is a **reference** to the tuple `(1, ,2, 3, 4)` and then becomes a **reference** to an empty tuple.

The tuple **values** are not modified.

Answer (score 3):

It's because line 2 isn't mutating the first tuple `tup`. Instead, it's creating a completely new tuple, then assigning it to the variable name `tup`. The first tup isn't being changed, it's being replaced.